# Angular 6 - How to use Angular's httpClient to see changes in the URI data

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular6

So I am trying to do something but feel like I am missing a piece of information.  I am working with the Angular 6 httpClient to get data from a URI. I have it working just fine to get the data once, but any changes in the URI do not update without making multiple get requests and multiple subscribes.  I was wondering how this code should work for monitoring changes in the URI.

```
let test = '';

getTestData(uriString) {
    return this.httpClient.get(uriString)
        .map((data) => {
            return data;
        });
}

this.getTestData('api/test')
    .subscribe(
        (info: any) => {
            this.test = info.result;
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

I guess my questions are:

- Is the httpclient.get method making a connection to that uriString
  that can be monitored (so if the value in 'api/test' changes, could I
  see those changes without making another get request?)
- if this is not the case, to continually monitor the changes to the URI, do I need to call the "getTestData" method over and over again to see any changes that are made (like in a setInterval)?  I thought the subscribe method is supposed to see changes, but so far it is not working like that.

Any clarification/help on this would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `httpClient` completes once it receives response. that means you need to call `get` again. if you need continuous monitoring of data change you probably need websockets or something similar.

Comment: First, arguments are passed by value in JavaScript/TypeScript. S there' is no way a method could know that the value that was passed as argument has changed. And no, you don't need to make a request again and again like in setInterval. You need to make a new request when you change the URI. That doesn't happen all by itself. If by "changing the URI", you don't actually mean that, but mean "when the value returned by a request to the same URI changes", than there is no way to know that without making a new request.

Answer (score 1):

With the obove code, you will only call the back-end API once, then wait for the HTTP response to finish and handle the result in your subscription. The observables completes afterwards.

You have two alternatives:

Either you use another RXJS observer creation function to trigger multiple calls to your API (e.g. `ìnterval`) or you implement `WebSockets` on both, client and server, which would enable "pushing" data from the server to the client on changes.

An example for interval would be:

`timeInterval(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get(uriString)))`